# As of 2011: Netbeans 7 or Eclipse Indigo for C++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, netbeans, ide, eclipse-cdt

This is basically a duplicate of:
[Netbeans or Eclipse for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308450/netbeans-or-eclipse-for-c)

But, that question as 3+ years old, and a lot has changed since then.

I have a large code base with a custom (but Makefile based) build system.  The areas I am specifically wondering about include:

1. Syntax highlighting
2. Code navigation.
3. Code hints.
4. "ReSharper style" code helpers.
5. Documentation integration.
6. Debugger UI and features.

Has anyone had the chance to evaluate both Netbeans and Eclipse?

EDIT:  As a followup question, are any of the Netbeans users here concerned with its future given Oracle's recent bad history with "open" efforts?  (Open Solaris, MySQL, Open Office)

Thank you

Comment: It would also be great to hear of experiences with QtCreator and Code::Blocks

Comment: fwiw, I've used the latest QtCreator. It's really nice, but still needs to mature a bit for use on big c/c++ projects.

Comment: for C++ i won't/don't use either of them. I use QtCreator sometimes when i really feel i need to use a debugger because i'm not very good at command line outputs of gdb. Otherwise i use vim. Code::Blocks also looks good these days.

Comment: I wont comment on the usability of NetBeans with regard to c++, as its not really something I have too much experience in. Regarding the future of NetBeans I don't  think there is too much to worry about as the NetBeans and JDeveloper teams seem to be working towards being able to share code. Its already started to some extent as the last version of [JDeveloper actually runs on NetBeans](http://java.dzone.com/news/jdev-flies-netbeans). See Jaroslav Tulachs entry on [JDeveloper](http://wiki.apidesign.org/wiki/JDeveloper) for more information

Comment: @Aditya: graphical gdb works fine in Eclipse. Visual studio has built in graphical debugger. not sure i follow your comment.

Comment: are you developing on Linux? otherwise, why not consider VS as well?

Comment: @sternr  yeah.. Am on both *nix and Linux.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I cannot comment on Netbeans, but I can offer you information on Eclipse.  I work with C++ on UNIX systems, and I have started to use Eclipse when exploring large code bases that I know little about.  I don't use it to build, but it would be easy to integrate our build system with it as one only needs commands.

Eclipse has most of what you are looking for: (I'm speaking of Eclipse/CDT)

1. Not only can you completely customize your syntax highlighting, you can also have it format the code with templates.  My company has a code standard for spacing, tabs and formatting of functions and conditional code, and with little effort I was able to modify an existing template to meet our code standards.
2. The navigation is not bad, if you highlight and hover over a variable, it shows you the definition in a small pop-up bubble.  If you do the same for a type, it will you show you where the type is defined.  For functions, it will show the first few lines of the implementation of the function, with an option to expand it and see the whole function.  I find all of these nice for code discovery and navigation.  You can also highlight a variable, and use a right-click menu option to jump to its declaration.
3. I suppose by code hints you are referring to something like intellisense?  This is the main reason why I use Eclipse when looking over a large code base.  Just hit the '.' or '->' and a second later you get your options.
4. The debugger UI is quite capable.  You can launch gdb within the tool and it allows you to graphically move through your code just as you would in a tool like ddd or Visual C++.  It offers standard features like viewing registers, memory, watching variables, etc.

That being said, I have found some weaknesses.  The first is that it doesn't really strongly support revision control systems outside of CVS and SVN very easily (integrated into the GUI).  I found a plug-in for the system we use at my company, but it spews XML and Unicode garbage.  It was easier to just use the revision control on the command line.  I suspect this is the plug-in's issue and not Eclipse.  I wish there were better tool integration though.

The second complaint is that for each project I have to manually setup the include directories and library paths.  Perhaps with an environment variable this could be circumvented?  Or I may just do not know how to set things up correctly.  Then again if it is not obvious to a developer how to do this, I consider that a weakness of the tool.

All in all I like working with Eclipse.  It is not my main editing environment, but I appreciate it for working on large code bases.

Comment: include directories and library paths.... supposedly pkg-config support should be already working in the latest version, but i haven't tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816492/eclipse-cdt-add-include-path-from-pkg-config

Comment: it fully supports Git, Perforce in my experience (integrated into GUI "team" context menus)

Comment: That is nice to know about Git.  At my office, bazaar is the source control software, and unfortunately the plug-in for bazaar does not work very well.

Answer (score 11):

I cannot comment on eclipse, but on netbeans 7 I will say things that are very important for me and that work fine so far:

- code completion, go to declarations
- pkg-config automatic include management for parsing

stuff that sometimes works and sometimes don't

- find usages, sometimes it might fail to find usages in other open projects
- debugger sometimes gets confused with unittest-cpp macros and it will not go on the appropiate line

stuff that are not yet working and i care deeply:

- C++0x syntax highlighting (auto, lambdas, enum class, variadic templates, none of them are recognized by the built-in parser)

stuff that is not quite working but i could not care less:

- git integration. I enjoy using git from command-line so this is a non-issue

in all, the IDE is very usable. I hope to have a chance to try out latest cdt on Indigo Eclipse, but so far i haven't that much of a real reason to investigate

Comment: Thank you. If you get a chance to try Eclipse Indigo, I'd like to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Eclipse Indigo seems to have pretty good support for C++0x, I think to gcc v4.5 (but not yet 4.6):

Comment: There's a plugin, nbgit, that provides some basic git support like diff highlighting and history browsing. It can't replace the command linke though.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a huge fan of Netbeans. I am in a similar situation to yours, but creating the project was very easy. Just point Netbeans at where the code is checked out and it figures out most things for itself. I rarely have to do any configuration. One thing to note though, if your tree is very large, it can take some time to fully index - and while it does, memory and cpu will be hosed on the box.

The integration with cvs is awesome, and the Hudson integration is very cool for CB. I've not used Git myself, though I should imagine it's a no-brainer.

One thing that does irritate me no end is that it does not behave very well with code relying heavily on templates. i.e. shows lots of warnings and errors about types not being found etc.

I have not used the latest version of Eclipse, I tried the major release before the current one and gave up because it did not have the same smooth project integration with the makefiles etc. I find it's not as nice if you don't want to use it's make system - though I could be wrong.

I don't use any of the code formatting provided, I instead prefer something like AStyle instead. I know that NetBeans does a good job with Java - but have not used it for C++. CDT I seem to remember doing some odd stuff with indentation when formatting C++ code - esp. if templates are involved - but that was atleast two years ago.

Hope some of it helps - the best way to do this is to download and try for yourself and see what works for you. Anything we tell you is purely subjective.

Answer (score 1):

I used to work with Netbeans with MinGW, I Just tried 7.0.1.
I currently use Eclipse Indigo with CDT and MinGW - It's better performance wise (less CPU & Memory).

Netbeans creates a makefile to compile all the time,
In Eclipse you can build directly with the CDT-Toolchain or use Makefile - Eclipse is more flexible.

Debugging: Netbeans might be better in Solaris/Linux.

I Personally rather eclipse over Netbeans, I think eclipse is more professional.

Answer (score 0):

One particular issue that causes me quite a lot of grief with Netbeans 7.0 is that it tends to want to work with utf8 files, and not all of out c++ projects are utf8. It will issue a warning about opening such a file, and if you do open it, will corrupt said file, which is a pain.

I've not found out how to properly make netbeans handle this. Apparently the encoding can be changed, but for the entire project. So presumably changing it to us-acii would stop this problem, although non ascii characters wouldn't display properly.